# Identify source widget when multiple widgets share the same callback

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

I create multiple widgets in a loop, and they all share the same callback. My problem is to identify the widget that triggers the callback.

I try to give the index of the widget as an argument of the callback like this:

```
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QSlider, QVBoxLayout, QWidget
import sys

class Foo(QWidget):
  def __init__(self, parent=None):
    super().__init__(parent)

    self.sliders = []
    for n in range(10):
      slider = QSlider(Qt.Horizontal)
      slider.valueChanged.connect(lambda: self.on_slider(n))
      self.sliders.append(slider)

    layout = QVBoxLayout()
    for slider in self.sliders:
      layout.addWidget(slider)
    self.setLayout(layout)

  def on_slider(self, n):
    print(n)


app = QApplication(sys.argv)
gui = Foo()
gui.show()
sys.exit(app.exec())
```

However this prints `9` for any slider that is moved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To obtain which object has emitted the signal there are several forms like:

1. You must first pass the parameter that returns the signal and then the other parameters.

---

```
slider.valueChanged.connect(lambda val, n=n: self.on_slider(val, n))

[...]

def on_slider(self, val, n):
    print(n, val)
```

**Complete code:**

```
class Foo(QWidget):
  def __init__(self, parent=None):
    super().__init__(parent)

    self.sliders = []
    for n in range(10):
      slider = QSlider(Qt.Horizontal)
      slider.valueChanged.connect(lambda val, n=n: self.on_slider(val, n))
      self.sliders.append(slider)

    layout = QVBoxLayout()
    for slider in self.sliders:
      layout.addWidget(slider)
    self.setLayout(layout)

  def on_slider(self, val, n):
    print(n)
```

2- Another way is to use `objectName` and `setObjectName` and the `sender` function that returns the object that emits the signal.

---

```
for n in range(10):
      slider = QSlider(Qt.Horizontal)
      slider.setObjectName(str(n))
      slider.valueChanged.connect(self.on_slider)

[...]

def on_slider(self, val):
    print(self.sender().objectName(), val)
```

**Complete code:**

```
class Foo(QWidget):
  def __init__(self, parent=None):
    super().__init__(parent)
    layout = QVBoxLayout(self)

    for n in range(10):
      slider = QSlider(Qt.Horizontal)
      slider.setObjectName(str(n))
      slider.valueChanged.connect(self.on_slider)
      layout.addWidget(slider)

  def on_slider(self, val):
    print(self.sender().objectName(), val)
```